# How to determine the counts of 0 and 1 in binary number with low time and space cost

Tags: c++

I want to write a function in C++ to determine the number of 0 and 1 in a binary number.
example:

```
input:1001100
output:number 1 counts 3;number0 counts 4.
```

The difficulty is the space cost and the time cost.My idea is use int to store the data，that will reduce space cost.
example:

```
input:1001100
1001100 = 76;
int x = 76;
int num0 = 0;
int num1 = 0;
while(x>0){
  if(x%2 >0)
    num1++;
  else
    num0++;
  x = x/2;
}
return num0,num1;
```

In this way,each int number will store 31 binary character,but time cost will be unacceptable.So I want to find an efficient function to reduce time cost.

Comment: _"but time cost will be unacceptable"_ Could you elaborate on this? What were the results of your benchmarks?

Comment: Hint: there are only 256 possibilities, and you can calculate the number of bits set, for all 256 possibilities, in advance. So, this becomes a laughably-trivial array lookup. Even an ancient Commodore 64, with a grand total of 64kb of RAM, won't have any problems with this.

Comment: Now in my way the time complexity is n,I want to reduce it to log(n) and less.

Comment: @GokberkYar The C++ code can't even be compiled with most compilers. You shouldn't link to Geeks for Geeks. The site is known low quality, many mistakes and bad code style.

Comment: For "small" sizes, you could perform a table (array) lookup.  This method is very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

So this is the code you're probably looking for in C++:

```
unsigned int TrueCount(unsigned int b)
{
    return __builtin_popcount(b); // true count;
    // return 32 - __builtin_popcount(b) // or false count;
}
```

That's for Clang. Visual C++ use __popcnt instead. Once you have the true count, you have the false count - it's just 32 take the true count. But how is that actually implemented on the CPU?

This is how the true count of a 32-bit unsigned integer is calculated in Clang (trunk build) with maximum optimisations - the input is in %edi, the output is in %eax:

```
  movl %edi, %eax
  shrl %eax
  andl $1431655765, %eax # imm = 0x55555555
  subl %eax, %edi
  movl %edi, %eax
  andl $858993459, %eax # imm = 0x33333333
  shrl $2, %edi
  andl $858993459, %edi # imm = 0x33333333
  addl %eax, %edi
  movl %edi, %eax
  shrl $4, %eax
  addl %edi, %eax
  andl $252645135, %eax # imm = 0xF0F0F0F
  imull $16843009, %eax, %eax # imm = 0x1010101
  shrl $24, %eax
  retq
```

A whole series of shifts, bitwise ands, additions, and a multiplication. To calculate from 32 bits, uses only 2 registers of storage, 12 maths operations, and no looping / branching.

This converts back to C++ as:

```
auto n = theInputNumber;
auto a = n;
a >>= 1u;
a &= 0x55555555;
n -= a;
a = n;
a &= 0x33333333;
n <<= 2u;
n &= 0x33333333;
a += n;
a >>= 4u;
a += n;
a &= 0xF0F0F0F;
a *= 0x1010101;
a >>= 24u;
return {a, 32- a}; // true count, false count
```

Comment: hey is there a name for this algorithm?

Comment: @CEPB • "variable-precision SWAR algorithm".  (Also known as "population count", "popcount", "sideways sum", or "bit summation".)

Answer (score 0):

The operation is called `popcount`.

There are built-in SIMD based methods. Those are the most efficient ones. Unfortunately, those aren't portable and will require a bunch of `#ifdefs`.

Alternatively, you can make lookup table for bytes and then use it for each byte of the integer and sum the result.

There is also a fast method with computation that could be used in cases when lookup/built-in methods aren't viable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. could you introduce the time cost of the function __builtin_popcount()?

Comment: @docetaxel time cost of a single operation? It depends on tons of things like your hardware. And it is never trivial to properly measure efficiency of functions.